# Passing and protecting $_GET[] variables from one server to another

Tags: php

I want to pass some variable to the URL using `PHP $_GET[''];` for example:

I have a form on a landing page with five input fields: Name, Surname, Email, Confirm-Email, Phone I pick these variables up now I want to add these to a Base URL so that they can be picked up by another web page.

My question is how safe is this and what is the best method to protect these variables or perhaps make them invisible under the new url...?

I could use php `curl()` or `sockets` but the server where I want to send the data to does not allow me to so thats why I want to `use $_GET['']'`

Comment: GET is never safe. Even non-tech users can type a URL. What are your exact needs? What do you want to protect against?

Comment: well I want to pass data from one web page to another where both sit on different server. the destination server does nto allow me any access neither php curl or sockiets, so the only way of making this happen I though of $_GET but I am aware of the risks, and though there might be some secure way of doing it.

Comment: Imagine you're building a house and you want it "risk free". Risks are endless (burglars, floods, earthquakes, fire, radioactivity, zombies...) but you probably have something specific in mind.

Comment: are you able to edit the landing page on the other server?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I understand your point and agree with you but isynt there at list some minimum security I can apply i really dont wont to end up with something like this: `www.example.com/home?name?surname?email?confirm_email?phone`

Comment: @Gustonez yes I have the full access to the server where the landing pages sit on therefore yes I can edit

Comment: Well, invalid data is not a security risk, unless it'll make the end server crash. Since you have full access to it, just make it validate input and ignore invalid params.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I already did the validation for the input data, my worry is if end up with a url like this: `www.example.com/home?name?surname?email?confirm_email?phone` is it ok for the data to be visible even if it passed validation..? it more about data protection I guess...?

Comment: If you have access to both pages, can't you encrypt the data and decrypt it?

Comment: @iWontStop I only have acces to the server where the lp sit on, but i dont have access to the data destination server

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$_GET` if you want to make your data secure.

There is no option using which you can make `$_GET` secure or invisible.

You should use `$_POST` for sending data to other url if you do not want to make your data visible and secure.

Even your data is not stored by browser when you use post method and it is more difficult to hack.

Comment: How can I send data to another server using $_POST if I have no access to the other server....? any other suggestions....?

Comment: there are some alternates mentioned in this link 
http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/
  http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php

Answer (score 0):

It's unsafe, as URI parameters can be edited by anyone and anything. Best method to "protect" those is to encrypt them when sending (which means the recipient must be able to decrypt them) combined with a checksum to make sure none of the parameters were altered. Another type of protection is not using HTTP but using HTTPS instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Both `GET` and `POST` is unsafe if you're not using HTTPS.

So if you have to use GET to submit your form, a verify token is suggeseted. Like OAuth, server will return the data through GET, but there's a `access_token` to protect data.

Answer (score 0):

Encode your variables first, then decode it on the other server. this way no one can easily revert it. Make sure to change `var $skey = "SecretKey0001";` to something else.

```
<?php 
class Encryption {
    var $skey   = "SecretKey0001"; // you can change it

    public  function safe_b64encode($string) {

        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public  function encode($value){ 

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }
}

$data_array['Name'] = 'Name';
$data_array['Surname'] = 'Surname';
$data_array['Email'] = 'Email';
$data_array['Confirm-Email'] = 'Confirm-Email';
$data_array['Phone'] = 'Phone';

$data_json = json_encode($data_array);

$encrypt = new Encryption;
$encoded_vars = $encrypt->encode($data_json);
$BASE_URL = 'http://example.com?data=' . $encoded_vars;
echo $BASE_URL;

echo "<br>";

// reverse
$decrypt = new Encryption;
echo $decoded_vars = $decrypt->decode($encoded_vars);
echo "<br>";
$data = json_decode(urldecode($decoded_vars), true);
echo "<br>";
print_r($data);

?>
```

DEMO: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef1acdcad0272d5d99e21b07183a479f564ac64c